# What is the differences between multithreading vs concurrent vs parallel vs asynchronous programming?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing

For a couple of days, I am wondering what is the difference between this four types of programming.I search information in Google but I cannot answer my question so I decide to ask you, can someone explain to me please? Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

The programming keywords you have mentioned refer to techniques invented for specific reasons to solve problems in the field of computation and processing.

A concise essence of what each technique aims to solve:

- **Concurrency**: There are many tasks at hand, I need a steadfast progress in each of them instead of completing one and moving on to the next in a serial approach. Let me work on each of the processes so that *at a given point in time*, there is **non-zero progress** in *two or more* tasks. (*not necessarily in simultaneity*)
- **Parallelism**: There is potential for doing more work in unit time given my device resources. Let me use some techniques **to increase throughput**, *possibly sacrificing latency*, so that my task(s) finish quicker.
- **Multi-threading**: *Both my device hardware and software* have support for more than one thread of execution in a program; Let me split the *computationally intensive calculations* **across** those processors/cores/thread-pools!
- **Asynchrony**: A set of tasks to be completed. **I am performing one of them currently**. Let me call my friend to help me out with another task, I hope *he/she comes back* to me with the results *while I continue* performing my task.

> Note that the techniques discussed above are not necessarily mutually
> exclusive.
> Specifically, multi-threading is a type of parallelism, which in turn does result in degree of concurrency being more than 1 (non-trivial multi-threading).

Incidentally, I've maintained a blog about parallel computing. In one of the posts, I've written about the jargon used in the same field.

https://magical-parallel-computing.blogspot.com/2017/04/parallel-computing-jargon.html

I hope it helps you at a conceptual level.

Comment: Re, "Concurrency":  Good explanation except, it sounds like you are saying that you can measure progress "at a given point in time."  I wonder if what you're trying to say is that two or more tasks can be _in_ progress at a given point in time (i.e., that tasks _overlap_).

Comment: You say that multi-threading means "... more than one thread of execution";  OK, but what is a "thread of execution?"  If you haven't tried to explain it to a newbie lately, then you might not remember how difficult it can be for some people to get the idea.  You can explain the implementation if the noob knows  what "execution context" and "call stack" mean.  And, at a higher level, you can talk about multi-threading as a way to organize a program that performs concurrent tasks and/or handles asynchronous events.

Comment: @james large Thanks! Oh, in the same point, I've mentioned that tasks need not necessarily be happening in simultaneity, so they don't need to overlap, like in case of co-routines, for example. If they do overlap in time, then it's not just concurrency, it is also parallelism; since an overlapped execution requires more than one processing unit/worker.

Comment: No, I think it's like what you said in your answer:  "Parallelism" is all about  exploiting hardware resources (e.g., using more than one CPU), while "concurrency" merely means that you can start one task while there is some other task that you have started, but not yet finished.  I've heard "overlap" formally defined as, "the _start event_ of one _interval_ lies between the start event and the _end event_ of some other interval."

Comment: @jameslarge Yes you are right! I wanted to keep the explanation as abstract as possible, looks like it worked well with concurrency, parallelism and asynchrony. However, since multi-threading is a specific type of parallelism, I had to include some contextual keywords without diving into the describing the fundamentals... Feel free to add some content if you like, I'd be glad to accept it!   :)

Comment: @jameslarge Huh? My answer and my first comment are consistent with one another! Yes, with that definition of overlap, as in, time interval overlapping, it should turn out correct. I interpreted it as processing overlap, which is a particular case... Anyway, thanks for the upvote!   ;D

Comment: _possibly sacrificing latency_ Why is that so?

Comment: @nprensen Hey there, that's a good question! Parallel compute units (like processes or threads) when spawned/initialized, always incur an overhead when compared to a single threaded process. This concept of _latency vs throughput_ is a key factor in most parallel computing techniques.

Comment: I think _Let me work on each of the processes so that at a given point in time..._ is a little misleading, since it might suggest simultaneity.  It's really that joint progress is made over _intervals_ of time.

Comment: @user1071847 You're right! I had already mentioned the same in brackets "(not necessarily in simultaneity)"   ;)