# What is the difference between concurrency and multithreading? (especially in Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is concurrency just a broader term and multithreading is one of types of concurrency ?

Comment: That duplicate should probably get you started. Add more dupes if you think it's missing info.

Comment: another possible dupe target specific to Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100102/what-is-the-differene-between-concurrency-and-multithreading

Comment: [What is the differences between multithreading vs concurrent vs parallel vs asynchronous programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764803/what-is-the-differences-between-multithreading-vs-concurrent-vs-parallel-vs-asyn)